Idle-Session-Timeout not working in next-auth js project
I am building a project using Next.js 14, so I have an app/ directory and don't have a pages/ directory. I am also using next-auth v5 beta for authentication and also this package called idle-session-timeout from npm.
I added this code in my layout.tsx of my homepage:
import { IdleSessionTimeout } from "idle-session-timeout";
import { auth, signOut } from "../api/auth/[...nextauth]/auth";

// some code here
const session = await auth();
let sessionTimeout = new IdleSessionTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
 
sessionTimeout.onTimeOut = () => {
// here you can call your server to log out the user
    console.log("timeOut");
};

sessionTimeout.start();
// rest of the code here

I get the following error (also shown in image):
Error: window is not defined
I believe the error is because this is a server component, but I cannot change is to client component because I need to use await auth().
How can I resolve this?

